# Select data from two tables with speed

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I have two tables that I want to select from. I have a table called `articles` which stores various articles for my content management system and I have another called `articles_meta_data` that stores meta data for the articles table. In order to get an article's meta data, you select from articles_meta_data using the `article Id`. My code is here and works perfectly. Is there a way I can optimize the code and make it faster?

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM articles");    
while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
    $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM articles_meta_data WHERE article_ID=" . $row->ID);
    while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_object($result2)) {
        var_dump($row2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a SQL JOIN, so you don't need to iterate executing the meta select for each article.

Comment: @MarkBaker how? Am sorry but I'm not that good in MySQL

Comment: The `mysql`-extension is outdated, not maintained anymore and it will be flagged as `deprecated` with 5.5. Use `PDO_MYSQL`, or `MySQLi` instead. http://php.net/en/mysql-connect

Answer (score 6, accepted):

join the tables so you will only query the database once, eg

```
SELECT  b.*
FROM    articles a
        INNER JOIN articles_meta_data b
            ON a.ID = b.article_ID
```

To further lean more about join, please see the link below

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)

Answer (score 0):

you should use join query so that you dont need to fire two queries, but first you have to decide which join to use for this check this link http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq93/

here we will use JOIN so that records with same value for columns articles.ID and articles_meta_data.article_ID will be selected

```
SELECT *,articles_meta_data.field1,articles_meta_data.field2 from articles JOIN articles_meta_data ON articles.ID = articles_meta_data.article_ID
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also do something like this..

```
Select * from articles JOIN articles_meta_data ON ID = article_ID
```

Hope this may also help you in some other way.